# Identity Server4 connect/token endpoint gives 400 Bad Request

Tags: identityserver4

We are using EntityFrameworkCore with Identity Server4. After initial setup, the discovery endpoint of identity server (`localhost:6000/.well-known/openid-configuration`) is working fine. When we tried to call the `connect/token` endpoint from postman it gives 400 bad request response. Here is our client:

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
{
    return new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client",

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { ApiResourceName.Sup_Api.Description() }
        },
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client2",

            // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,

            // secret for authentication
            ClientSecrets =
            {
                new Secret("secret".Sha256())
            },

            // scopes that client has access to
            AllowedScopes = { "sup"}
        }
    };
}
```

Here is postman connect/token post request:

```
http://localhost:6000/connect/token
  ?client_id=client2
  &client_secret=secret
  &grant_type=client_credentials
  &scope=sup
```

Response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You don't pass the parameters via the query string. It's meant to be in the body, using a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

See: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3

Comment: thanks @Scott, It's working fine now when i am using content type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Comment: I am still getting same error my url is:       http://localhost:5000/connect/token?client_id=client&client_secret=secret&scope=client_credentials&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @mocco you are sending the token request in the query string. You cannot do that. Instead, you have to send it via the form body.

Answer (score 4):

Make it **HTTP POST** request instead of browser's HTTP GET request

Answer (score 1):

Working Postman example:

[image]

I'm not sure about the redirect_uri value. But as response I'm getting:

- id_token
- access_token
- refresh_token

and some others.